# Html to PDF using Xam.iTextSharpLGPL in xamarin android

Tags: html, pdf, xamarin

I'm trying to convert an HTML code into a pdf file using Xam.iTextSharpLGPL in Xamarin Android. The problem is: All CSS part of my HTML's code is not interpreted, so the final design is different between the HTML and pdf files. In sume the PDF file is in an incorrect format.

My code to convert is that one:

```
public static void CreatePdf(string html_texto)
        {
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
            string pdfPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "samplee.pdf");
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            document.Open();
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.Append(html_texto);
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(html.ToString());
            worker.StartDocument();
            worker.Parse(reader);
            worker.EndDocument();
            worker.Close();
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

My html file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            table.itens {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

            table.itens tr {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.a,
            table.itens thead tr.a {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: rgb(191, 253, 212);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.a td,
            table.itens thead tr.a td {
                background-color: rgb(191, 253, 212);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.b,
            table.itens thead tr.b {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: rgb(218, 254, 230);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.b td,
            table.itens thead tr.b td {
                background-color: rgb(218, 254, 230);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.c,
            table.itens thead tr.c {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: rgb(228, 254, 230);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.c td,
            table.itens thead tr.c td {
                background-color: rgb(228, 254, 230);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.d,
            table.itens thead tr.d,
            table.itens tbody tr td,
            table.itens thead tr td {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr.d td,
            table.itens thead tr.d td {
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }

            table.itens tbody tr td {
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 3px;
                background: transparent;
                text-align: left;
            }

            table.itens thead tr td {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                padding: 3px;
                background: transparent;
                text-align: left;
            }

            table {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 1px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

            table .thead tr,
            table .tbody tr {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            table .thead tr th {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 3px;
                background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60);
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }

            table .thead tr td {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 3px;
                background-color: rgb(76, 175, 80);
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }

            table .tbody tr td {
                padding: 3px;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .hide-this {
                display: none;
            }

            .ordem {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 3px;
                background-color: rgb(56, 142, 60);
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .operations {
                width: 100%;
                background: white;
            }

            .order-title-image img {
                height: 15px;
                width: 15px;
                float: right;
            }

            div.operations table > tbody.thead tr td {
                background: #A1A1A1;
            }

            .ordem > tr:nth-child(1) {
                height: 20px;
            }

            .ordem > tr.clickable:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function abrir(componente) {
                var tabela = componente.parentNode.parentNode;
                var linha = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
                var coluna = linha.getElementsByTagName('td');
                if (linha) {
                    if (linha.style.display == 'table-row') {
                        linha.style.display = 'none';
                        componente.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = componente.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.replace('recolher', 'expandir');
                    } else {
                        coluna.colspan = '4';
                        linha.style.display = 'table-row';
                        componente.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = componente.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.replace('expandir', 'recolher');
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
            <thead class='thead'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='4'> RESUMO DO PEDIDO 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class='hide-this'>
                    <td colspan='4'>EMPRESA DO PEDIDO</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class='tbody hide-this'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Nome:</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Telefone:</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class='thead'>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='4'>DADOS DO CLIENTE</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class='tbody'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Código:</td>
                    <td>7549</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Razão Social:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Nome Fantasia:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>CNPJ/CPF:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>IE/RG:</td>
                    <td>ISENTO</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Endereço:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Bairro:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Cidade:</td>
                    <td>
                        <DEFINIR></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Telefone:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class='thead'>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='4'>DADOS DO PEDIDO</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

What can I do to convert my HTML to a PDF and keep the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this dependency there is no way to convert the HTML and keep the desing. The library doesn't interpret html on multiples pages, but just one.

To solve my problem I left this library and make the same way the gmail does to print an email. To make that, I added this text on html file:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" nonce="">
            // <![CDATA[
            document.body.onload = function () {
                document.body.offsetHeight;
                window.print();
            };
            // ]]>
        </script>
```

Using on that way the app tries to print the document, so is possible to save as PDF file.